# Ignore assumptions and still go ahead with a parametric test?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, stata, nonparametric

I have data which is not normally distrubuted (histogram doesnt show a bellshape data and normal plot shows a bit of a zig zag data going through line of best fit) but standard deviations are of similar size. As a result, i cannot use repeated measures ANOVA since data didnt meet one of the assumptions. Now, the nonparametric of repeated measures of ANOVA is the Friedman test, however, im using stata and this statistical package does not have this test in the programme. I wanted to get your opinion on if it would be okay to use repeated measures ANOVA even though data is non-parametric or would this really give me false results?

Looking forward to hearing your opiniona. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few packages for Stata that perform Friedman's test, or refined versions of it:

**skillmack** implements Skillings-Mack test (a generalization of the Friedman test)

Within Stata type: `net describe st0167, from(http://www.stata-journal.com/software/sj9-2)`

**friedman** and **kendall** perform Friedman's test and Kendall's normalization of it

Within Stata type: `net describe snp2_1, from(http://www.stata-journal.com/software/sj5-2)`

Comment: @EmmaDixon Incidentaly, if you wanted to use the So-And-So test (a very famous test, don't you know ;) in Stata, and the So-And-So test *is not* built into the basic installation, you can type `findit So-And-So test` to potentially pull up a list of packages that *do* perform it (assuming you are connected to the Internet). If and when you do so, you can just click on the blue links to follow the leads to description and installation.